# Super Key not opening launcher

Tags: unity, macbook, macbook-air

Alright so I have 12.04 installed on my macbook air and somehow it is not recognizing any key as being the <kbd>Super</kbd> key both the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and the <kbd>Command</kbd> key are coming up as an <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and I solved it by changing the ~/.Xmodmap file to the one provided by [dfacto](http://almostsure.com/mba42/dotXmodmap). It is not perfect (the alt and super keys are switched by default, and it changes the trackpad to "natural" scrolling) but at least you have a super key. I guess that by understanding how Xmodmap works, this can be solved.

Comment: What does this mean:  "it changes the trackpad to "natural" scrolling" I have also a MacBook Air with the same problem. But I don't want to change the trackpad-properties to get the cmd-key as windwos-key working.